# php lanza error Notice: Undefined index: imagen in C:\xampp\htdocs\libreria\añadirProducto.php on line 98

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un código php con mysql y quiero añadir/dar de alta productos a la tabla productos, su ultima columna es 'imagen' y quiero que a través de un input el usuario pueda subir una imagen y que esta se inserte en la base de datos, pero a la hora de testearlo todas las columnas funcionan excepto la de imagen, me esta lanzando el siguiente error: php lanza error Notice: Undefined index: imagen in C:\xampp\htdocs\libreria\añadirProducto.php on line 98. Se que es por introducir la variable imagen pero no consigo entender por qué, ¿alguien que me pueda ayudar?

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
        header('Location: Ejer6.php');
    
    include_once 'claseConexion.php';

    // Inicializar variables a mostrar en formulario
    $error = null;
    $nombre = ''; $pvp = '';
    $prod_insertado = '';
    
    // Tratamiento del formulario
    if ( isset($_POST['Enviar']) ) {
        
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $pvp = $_POST['pvp'];
        
        $error = validar_datos($_POST);
        
        if ( $error['errNombre'] == "" && $error['errPvp'] == "" ) { // no hay errores
            $prod_insertado = insertar_producto($_POST);
        }
        
    }
    else if ( isset($_POST['Limpiar']) ) {
        $error = null;  $tabla = '';  $nombre = '';  $pvp = '';
    }
    
    function validar_datos($datos) {
        
        $error = array('errNombre' => '', 'errPvp' => '');
        
        if ( $datos['nombre'] == "" )
            $error['errNombre'] = "Debe introducir el nombre del producto";
            
            if ( $datos['pvp'] == "" )
                $error['errPvp'] = "Debe introducir el precio del producto";
                
                if ( $datos['nombre'] != "" && $datos['pvp'] != "" ) {
                    if ( !is_numeric($datos['pvp']) )
                        $error['errPvp'] = 'Precio: <b>'.$datos['pvp'].'</b> Debe ser numérico <br/>';
                        if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zñÑáéíóú\d_\s]{1,28}$/i', $datos['nombre']) )
                            $error['errNombre'] = 'Nombre: <b>'.$datos['nombre'].'</b> Debe ser alfanumérico <br/>';
                }
                
                return $error;
    }
    
    /* Genera un control select simple con los cifs de los proveedores. Admite un
     posible parámetro de entrada para indicar si alguno de los cifs está seleccionado.
     */
    function lista_proveedores($selec='') {
        try
        {
            $BD = new ConectarBD();
            $conn = $BD->getConexion();
            
            $sql = 'SELECT cif, nom_emp FROM editoriales';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
            // Empezar a generar el control
            $salida = '';
            $salida .= "<select class=\"form-control\" name='selProveedor'><br/>";
            while ( $prov = $stmt->fetch() ) {
                if ( $prov['cif'] == $selec )
                    $salida .= "  <option value='". $prov['cif'] .  $prov['cif']." " . $prov['nom_emp'] . "' selected=\"selected\">" . $prov['cif']. "</option><br/>";
                    else
                        $salida .= "  <option value='" . $prov['cif'] ."'>" . $prov['cif']." " . $prov['nom_emp']."</option><br/>";
            }
            $salida .= '</select><br/>';
            
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            
            $BD->cerrarConexion();
            
            return $salida;
            
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $BD->cerrarConexion();
            die ("¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
        }
    }
    
    /* Realiza la inserción en la BD de un producto indicado como parámetro.
     * Devuelve una cadena de caracteres en formato tabla con los datos de la
     * fila insertada.
     */
    function insertar_producto($producto) {
        
        $nombre = $producto['nombre'];
        $precio = $producto['pvp'];
        $proveedor = $producto['selProveedor'];
        $imagen = $producto['imagen'];
        
        $salida = '';
        
        try
        {
            $BD = new ConectarBD();
            $con = $BD->getConexion();
            
            $sql = 'SELECT max(cod)+1 as cod FROM productos';
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $codigo = $stmt->fetch();
            
            $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO productos VALUES '
                . '(:cod, :nom_prod, :pvp, :edit, :imagen)');
            $stmt->execute( array( ':cod' => $codigo['cod'],
                ':nom_prod' => $nombre,
                ':pvp' => $precio,
                ':edit' => $proveedor,
                ':imagen' => $imagen ) );
            
            if ( $stmt->rowCount() == 1 ) {
                $salida .= '<p class="text-center"><h4>Datos insertados</h4></p>';
                $salida .= '<table class=" table table-striped"><tr>';
                $salida .= "<td>".$codigo['cod']."</td><td>".$nombre."</td><td>".
                    $precio."</td/><td>".$proveedor."</td><td>".$imagen."</td>";
                    $salida .= '</tr></table><br>';
            }
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            
            $BD->cerrarConexion();
            
            return $salida;
            
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $BD->cerrarConexion();
            die ("¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
        }
        
    }
    
    ?>

<!-- Parte cliente del script PHP.

     Presenta un formulario de entrada con el nombre y precio del producto, así
     como un control simple para seleccionar el CIF del proveedor.
     En caso de errores de validación después de pulsar el botón Enviar se 
     mantienen los datos introducidos.
     Presenta mensajes de error justo debajo de cada campo del formulario.
     En caso de inserción en BD correcta muestra los datos en forma de tabla. 
-->     

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head> 
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/estilos_flex.css' />      
   </head> 
   <body> 
      
        <header>
          <?php include_once 'cabecera.php'; ?>
        </header>
     
        <?php include_once 'navegacion.php'; ?>   
       
        <section>    
            <div id="caja1">
            
                <div><p>Conectado como usuario: <strong> 
                    <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'] ?></strong><p> </div>
                
                <div id="alta">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
                        
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>                 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" 
                                value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>"  
                                placeholder="Nombre Producto"/>
                        
                        <p class='alert-danger'><?php echo $error['errNombre']; ?></p>
                       
                            <label for="precio">Precio:</label>                    
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pvp" id="precio" 
                                value="<?php echo $pvp; ?>"  
                                placeholder="Precio Producto" />
                        
                        <p class='alert-danger'><?php echo $error['errPvp']; ?></p>
                       
                           <label for="proveedor">Proveedor:</label>                 
                           <?php if (isset($_POST['selProveedor']))
                                    echo lista_proveedores($_POST['selProveedor']); 
                                 else echo lista_proveedores(); ?>
                                 
                        <p class='alert-danger'><?php echo $error['errPvp']; ?></p>
                         
                         <input type="file" name="fichero" value="<?php echo $imagen; ?>" />Imagen:            
                          <br><br>
                                        
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Enviar" 
                                    value="Enviar">Insertar</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Limpiar" 
                                    value="Limpiar">Limpiar</button>
                        </div>
                         
                    </form>
                </div>    
            </div>  
            
            <aside>
                <?php include_once 'aside.php'; ?> 
            </aside>
            
        </section>    
          
        <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">  
            <?php echo $prod_insertado; ?> 
        </article>  
         
        <footer>
            <?php include_once 'pie.php'; ?>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="file" name="fichero" value="<?php echo $imagen; ?>" />Imagen:
```

Estas utilizando la variable `$imagen`  pero no le estas asignando ningún valor

PD: Le asignas un valor, pero adentro de una función pero la variable `$imagen` no es gobal por edén no la reconoce

la respuesta seria definir la variable `$imagen = "";` al principio del código

```html
 // Inicializar variables a mostrar en formulario
    $error = null;
    $nombre = ''; $pvp = '';
    $prod_insertado = '';
    $imagen = '';
```